# Управление ViewPager'ом

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Я начинающий Андроид-разработчик.

Хочу сделать решение тестов (вопросы с ответами) так, что бы только 1 вопрос из теста отображался на экране. Пользователь может ответить, а может и пропустить вопрос (ответить позже. после последнего вопроса пользователя бросает на вопрос без ответа). При ответе/пропуске пользователь переходит к след. вопросу. С помощью чего такое можно реализовать? Я думаю в сторону ViewPager, но не уверен что это возможно будет сделать.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону думать и с чем лучше работать.

Comment: Из того что вы написали нет ничего сложного в реализации. https://github.com/TechFreak/WizardPager вот посмотрите на реализацию если думаете сами пилить или можете просто заюзать

Comment: Спасибо! Буду разбираться)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подготавливаешь данные - коллекцию моделей или таблицу в БД. Содержимое: вопрос, ответ, состояние (отвечен или нет - дефолтное "не отвечен").

Дальше в одной активити манипулируешь этими данными.
На разметку вешаешь `TextView` и `EditText` или `RadioGroup`  с вариантами ответов (берешь из коллекции/БД) и кнопку "Пропустить". В `TextView` выводшь вопрос из первой позиции коллекции или первой строки БД, проверив его состояние -если не отвечен. Через `EditText` или `RadioGroup`  получаешь ответ пользователя. Сверяешь с верным из коллекции или БД . По результату проверки отмечаешь состояние в коллекции или БД для этой позиции/строки. 
Переходишь к следующей позиции/строке и делаешь то же самое, что выше. В тот же `TextView` выводишь вопрос со следующей позиции и тд.
Когда вопросы кончаются повторяешь все заново, пока все состояния не будут отмечены отвеченными или пока не нажмут закончить.
Выводишь результаты вдругой активити.

Как то так. И никакие пэйджеры тут не понадобятся. Две активити (с вопросами/ответами и для результатов) и упорядоченные данные с вопросами/ответами.

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую этот вариант)

Comment: слушай, я вот в цикле вывел из коллекции 1 вопрос с вариантами ответов и брейком закончил, но никак не пойму как мне реагировать на нажатия клавиш Пропустить/Ответить. Т.е. отобразить следующий вопрос

Comment: @itslayo Заводишь переменную - поле класса, содержащюю номер текущего вопроса. Пишешь метод, который будет выводить в поля на разметке данные - вопрос в `TextView` и варианты ответов (в что они там у вас выводятся). В качестве аргумента метод принимает номер вопроса, который соответствует позиции в коллекции вопросов и ответов. В слушателях кнопок управляешь номерами вопросов\позициями в коллекции - состоянием переменной ( прибавляешь или отнимаешь или что надо в текущей ситуации), затем вызываешь этот метод, чтобы отобразить новые данные с изменившейся позицией.